# How do I remove footer/watermark from Google Data Studio in an embedded report?

Tags: wordpress, embed, looker-studio

I'm redisplaying a Google Data Studio report on my [wordpress site](https://macrotickets.com/sports-wall/) via the html embed box. For this particular report I don't want viewers to know the backend is data studio. I've tried readjusting the viewing size to be smaller than that of the report in hopes it would trim out the footer but have had no luck.

Below is the code placed in the html embed box:

```
<iframe width="2000" height="1600" src="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/12EqvlygNlYq0D2zpHyNFe3CbswPAC_fT/page/xV>>>>DLB" frameborder="none" style="border:none" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Does anyone know how I could remove the google data studio report footer/watermark from my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t remove the data studio watermark without violating the Data Studio terms of service

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to find the following line in HTML.

```
<div ng-if="reportViewCtrl.isReportEmbedding()">
```

2. when a page is loaded use JS to add the following attribute:

```
style="display:none"
```

3. All together will look as follows

```
<div ng-if="reportViewCtrl.isReportEmbedding()" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

3 easy steps:

1. Disable with ajax/jquery/... the right click function to prevent them from being able to inspect the element embedded and get the url anyway
2. With CSS, load anything that you can use to overlay it on embedded datastudio footer.
3. That same element, make it transparent to avoid google penalties